# Images sometimes falling to the bottom of the page in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, magento

I have an issue with images sometimes falling to the bottom of the page when viewing in Internet Explorer.

http://www.comptonandwoodhouse.co.uk/jewellery

http://www.comptonandwoodhouse.co.uk/figurines

home-decor
collectables
bears
fashion
<< also try these links

- if you go to one of these pages in IE - just try them all, and then try them again a few times if you don't see it - the images will sometimes have fallen to the bottom of the page. I'm wondering if anyone knows what the problem might be?

Thanks,
Theo.

Comment: I can only reproduce it in IE7.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the main column gets too wide to float next to the sidebar, which pushes it to the bottom of the page.

I'm not sure why it only happens randomly...could be a css or javascript file doesn't load in time, or maybe your ecommerce system doesn't resize the thumbnails in time.

You could try adding a conditional stylesheet for IE7 and lower that makes the main column a little narrower to compensate:

```
<![if lt IE 8]>
.product_listing_rt {
float: left;
width: 700px; /* normally 711px */
}
<![endif]>
```